# CSS Transform Translate positioning is different in Chrome vs. Firefox?

Tags: css, transform, translate

Hi I'm having problems with the positioning of a pseudo element on my website. It is centered correctly over the hero video in Chrome, but in Firefox, it is all the way to the right side. This is the CSS:

```
.hero-container {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100% !important;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 50% 100%, 0 90%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 50% 100%, 0 90%, 0 0);
}


.hero-container::after {
  content: 'Welcome Home.';
  z-index: 5000;
  background-color: rgba(36,88,141,0.7);
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'PTSerifRegular', verdana, arial, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-40%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-40%);
}
```

This is the website-in-progress: http://ciminocarestg.wpengine.com/

Any hints on how this can be fixed or if there is a better way this can be accomplished? I'm using Bootstrap (well, UnderStrap) for the website and it is built on Wordpress if that helps any.

Thanks.

Comment: you are missing `left:50%`

Comment: @Temani Afif Oh my that really did the trick! Strange how `left:50%` wasn't required in Chrome! Thank you so much!